# How to pass variable as long text in spring boot Entity to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I got error:

> Data truncation: Data too long for column 'profile' at row 1

My stored variable photo down here:

[image: img of variable store in database]

my entity code down here:

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile_master")
public class profileEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int p_id;
    private String profile;
    private String website;
    private String bio;
    private String gender;

    // getter setter

}
```

Comment: It's too long for the MySQL column because it has type `varchar(255)`, try to use `text` which allows 65,535 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the entity definition you can explicitly mention the column length as follows,

```
@Column(length = 2000)
```

or you can change the column type to text which can hold up to 65,535 bytes.

```
@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
```